# Angular - Trying to sync two drop downs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to sync two drop downs in Angular 1.4.7 so that when one dropdown is updated the other is set to the same value, and vice-versa.  Seems like im close but instead of being synced, the other drop down changes to the default "select" value.

This is a simplified version of an issue on a site im working on.  The site in question is very data driven, so I'm hoping to get this to work within this structure.  That is, an array of inputData objects that each contain array of months & a selectedMonth attribute.

The application works fine, except for this new requirement.  What am I missing?

I included the source and a plunker showing the issue.

https://plnkr.co/edit/wSsBO4dHP0SR6HliP0b8?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="input in inputData">

     <select name="inputMonth__{$index}}" id="inputMonth__ID_{{$index}}" 
            ng-model="input.selectedMonth"
            ng-change="option_changed(input)"
            ng-options="month as month for month in input.Months "  >
        <option value="" style="display:none">Select</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>

</div>
```

**controller - test.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {


    $scope.inputData=[];
    $scope.inputData.push(new inputData());
    $scope.inputData.push(new inputData());


    $scope.option_changed = function(Input) {

        SyncDropdowns(Input)


    };

        function SyncDropdowns(selectedInput){


            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inputData.length ; i++) {

                var currInput=$scope.inputData[i];
                if (currInput!=selectedInput){
                    currInput.selectedMonth=$.extend({}, selectedInput.selectedMonth);

                }
            }
    }


    function inputData(){
        this.selectedMonth={};
        this.Months=["April", "May", "June", "July"];
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you intend to do here with

> currInput.selectedMonth=$.extend({}, selectedInput.selectedMonth);

I changed it to simply the following and it syncs up fine.

```
currInput.selectedMonth=selectedInput.selectedMonth;
```

Here is the [working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pv5AjndeBHZeYPWqqsFD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The jquery extend

```
$.extend({},"June")
```

returns

```
{
    "0": "J",
    "1": "u",
    "2": "n",
    "3": "e"
}
```

Update this function

```
function SyncDropdowns (selectedInput) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inputData.length ; i++) {
        var currInput=$scope.inputData[i];
        if (currInput!=selectedInput){
            currInput.selectedMonth=selectedInput.selectedMonth;
        }
    }
}
```

[updated plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/lKZPwABKRi8uH88zwMkO?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Inside ng-repeat each instance gets its own scope. Try using `$parent.input.selectedMonth` in `ng-model`